# Why does the base parameter give an error in the layout inflator?

Tags: android, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I am creating a custom `BaseAdapter` class,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    CustomAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String> items)
    {

        this.c=c;
        this.items=items;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View v= view;
        TextView tv;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ViewHolder pattern;

        if(view==null)
        {

            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy,viewGroup,true);



            tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            pattern = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(pattern);
        }
        else{
            pattern = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
            return v;
        }

        pattern.tv.setText(items.get(i));



        return v;
    }
}
```

I get this error,

```
addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

It is because I am passing a `true` in this code,

```
v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy,viewGroup,true);
```

My Question is why is there an error when we pass true here ? Doesn't `BaseAdapter` accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean parameter in the inflate method determines if the created view should be added to the ViewGroup you provided as second parameter. [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

Since your 2nd parameter is an AdapterView, Android will try to add the view directly to the AdapterView.
But AdapterView doesn't suppport the addView() method [ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#addView%28android.view.View%29)

You are not supposed to add the view directly to the ViewGroup in the getView() method. Just return it and you should be fine.

Comment: The 2nd parameter is the ListView right ? How can it be the Adapterview ?

Comment: Because a ListView is an AdapterView inheritance-wise. ListView and its ancestors don't override this method - probably to prevent misusage ;)

Comment: So you mean we cannot add a view to a list view or an adapter view ?

Comment: Not via the addView(...) methods. Your supposed to write Adapters that create those views. The framework will take care of adding the views to the list IF they become visible and may reuse existing instances.

Comment: Got it clear now we only have to define the views, the android system will take care of adding them to the lists.